# How to set up my VLANs correctly?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, proxmox

This is gonna be a little bit of a specific scenario: I have some problems with setting up my VLANs on my TL-SG108E and Proxmox server.

Here is what I want to achieve:

- A VLAN for users, only able to access each other
- A vlan for admins able to access all VLANS
- A vlan for Server configuration (Proxmox GUI and SSH)
- A VLAN for my "home VMs" that are for "internal use" only
- A VLAN for shared VMs (that can be accessed by other people remotely, this is done by VPN)

This is the current VLAN setup on the switch:
[image: 802.1Q VLAN setup on TL-SG108E]

Now this works great in theory, with the following setup in proxmox:
[image: Proxmox node networking setup]

One small issue is that this way, for some reason VMs set to VLAN 40 or 50 can access the user (10) VLAN, the other server VLAN (40 or 50 respectively), which is not intended. They can also ping both the switch (switch2) that they are connected to on VLAN 1, and another switch (switch1) that is connected to the router, also on VLAN 1 (I really don't know if this is normal actually).

Other than this, all is working correctly, as far as I know.

Network topology:

```
                        ┌─────┐
                        │Modem│
                        └──┬──┘
                           │
                        ┌──┴───┐
                        │Router│
                        └┬────┬┘
                         │    │
         ┌───────────────┘ │  └──────────────┐
         │                 │                 │
    ┌────┴───┐  Downstairs │ Upstairs   ┌────┴───┐
    │Switch 1│             │            │Switch 2│
    └┬───┬──┬┘             │            └┬───┬──┬┘
     │   │  │              │             │   │  │
 ┌───┘   │  └────┐         │          ┌──┘   │  └────┐
 │       │       │         │          │      │       │
┌┴─┐ ┌───┴───┐ ┌─┴─┐       │        ┌─┴─┐ ┌──┴──┐ ┌──┴───┐
│AP│ │IoT Hub│ │PC2│       │        │PC1│ │TV-PC│ │Server│
└──┘ └───────┘ └───┘       │        └───┘ └─────┘ └──────┘
```

Can anybody make any suggestion on what I should do differently? My config might be all wrong, as it is just experimental right now, and I'm no expert at this (if you couldn't tell).

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: Does the router support configuring separate, routed ports, ie. in different subnets? Most consumer-grade routers just use an internal switch for the LAN ports, without being able to split them. Do the router and Proxmox host support tagged VLANs?

Comment: The router is an edgerouter x, basically all vlans work fine as I expected them, except these ones for the server, which can access stuff they shouldn't. Proxmox needs the VLANs to be tagged to use them.

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason VMs set to VLAN 40 or 50 can access the user (10) VLAN, the other server VLAN (40 or 50 respectively), which is not intended. They can also ping both the switch (switch2) that they are connected to on VLAN 1, and another switch (switch1) that is connected to the router, also on VLAN 1 (I really don't know if this is normal actually).

Each VLAN is a separate link-layer segment. Communication between VLANs is only possible when you use distinct IP subnets and route between them. That seems to happen on the Edgerouter.

You need to add firewall/forwarding rules on the Edgerouter to permit only the communication that you want to happen. Anything else should be denied.

Comment: The VLANs show up as connected networks in the routing table. I don't seem to be able to do anything with them, but will take a look. Can you please confirm that my swith vlan settings are okay tho? Or are they bullcrap?